# Could not create a maven script with such a dependency (interdependent projects)

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a case where there are multiple projects and each are interdependent and I could not create a maven script with such a dependency because jars wont be ready to use as both are interdependent. Do we have a solution for such cases in maven? The solution what i see here are below:

1. Remove the dependency between the projects means change the code to remove such interdependent.
2. Merge two projects into one in the build - means create single jar by picking up source from 2 projects.

I dont want to do either of do as it needs additional efforts to do so.

Is there a way source of one project can be used in another project and not being part of JAR?

Answer (score 0):

In Maven you cannot build interdependent jars. This problem also arose in our company when we moved legacy projects to Maven. In my opinion one should really put effort into solving this situation, so use your proposals (1) or (2) or generate a third project which contained the shared classes on which both jars depend. Any "trick" to avoid this would be as complicated and lead to a bad project structure.

Comment: Do we have anything in maven like can use include to get all required java files from other project only for supporting compilation and excluding those files while packaging the jar.

Comment: I don't think so and it seems like a horrible thing to do. Why not just merge the jars?